# Teradata Database Docker Image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, teradata

I've browsed the web and could not find a satisfactory answer. **Is there an existing Docker image to run Teradata database in a Docker container?**

All I've found so far is this repository which conains Docker Images for Hadoop Hive, Presto, etc... but not for Teradata database itself.

Comment: Currently there's only a VMWare image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mention by dnoeth. Currently there's only a VMWare image.